# Image resize results in vertical bars (python & PIL)

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

This in being used in django view.

Im trying to reduce the size of a incoming image to create an thumbnail. To simplify things, I made the resize width/height the same as the original image (i've tried making it smaller and the exact same problem occurred.

```
    basewidth = 350
    baseheight = 467
    img = Image.open(aobj.useravatar)
    img.convert('RGB')  # suggestion found in stackoverflow 
    img.resize((basewidth, baseheight), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(file, format='JPEG', quality=100)
```

When downloaded, the file looks like this:
[Vertical Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLAFg.jpg)

The original file (take from the server) looks like this:
[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfoXF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I save the files as a "PNG" the resultant image is perfect, so the code s/b:

```
basewidth = 350
baseheight = 467
img = Image.open(aobj.useravatar)
img.thumbnail((basewidth, baseheight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save(file, format='PNG', quality=100)
```

Yayyy.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
basewidth = 350
baseheight = 467
img = Image.open(aobj.useravatar)
img = img.thumbnail((basewidth, baseheight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save(file, format='JPEG', quality=100)
```